# ruby - %w(%q(words in a row)) returns wrong elements

Tags: ruby, arrays

How can I get this expression to return an array of words?

```
%w(%q(words in a row))
```

I thought that %q would give me a string and then %w would give me an array of the words.
Bt instead I get

```
["%q(words", "in", "a", "row")"]
```

This is part of some larger code so just using %w on its own will not help.
I want to be able to interpolate the %q expression first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lower case `%w` and `%q` does not interpolate variables inside. You will need to use upper case `%W` and `%Q`, and also you need to wrap the variable with `#{}` to interpolate.

Your version of working code:

```
%W{#{%q{words in a row}}}
```

However just as Justin said, I do not understand the point of this. You can directly put raw string without quotes in `%w{}`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the problem. But if you want to interpolate the string and then convert to a word array, I believe the `%W` does this, noting the capitalization (see [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals)).

```
%W(words in a row)
#=> ["words", "in", "a", "row"]
```

Comment: Normally I would just use this but I needed interpolation (code is snippet of much larger base).

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Honestly if it is a big base, String#split will do a better job.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the usefulness of doing such thing, and there is definitely a smell in your code, but here is a way:

```
eval("%w(#{%q(words in a row)})")
# => ["words", "in", "a", "row"]
```